# Proper use of TypeScript Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My goal here is to have requests and responses grouped by action, so if I have (as in the code below) two actions: `Play` and `Stay`, I will have a pair of request/response representing the request/response of `Play` action and the same for the `Stay` action.

I want to express the constraint that only request and response of the same action can be coupled ([see Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20211212&ssl=58&ssc=61&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYDkCGBbaBeKAIgAUAbTEQqAHyIGVgLCBuAKFdEigCUIBHAK4QAzsAAiAHhhQIAD2ARUAE2GwEKDDggAaKACEZ8xSp4Q4yAE5KJoi4lQBzXQNQBrVMgDuqAHw+oBADerFBQAPqMDgBcRLyCIsAsIeGY6mgxMGwAvlAAZPpsHODQvMJgaMIQktJyCsqq8EhoWLi6BrXGqrzmVjbAdo7Obh7efgFQwaERmNGxIuWolUlTqU2oGdl5Beyc0GQUcUKi44cJkiTklLqBUJgxqALYAEYQFlBZPmy7UPsgpQuVE7zCpVCQXJjXKBPe6PF5vD6Fb4MA78I7AIHxUTnZFXCZQOAw56vd6fIpcHH-EFAsog7GMXE3JSEuEkxHFNRrADyADMJAANfwEPmGOomU5YiT2bnEmC6TCoEA+ZIAflgyRiwo69VMNMWoKlMrlCqVoVVMHVUFQEAAbq9CgB6e0-CzIJ6kCDYKKsR1QYWIVQAA3BlBo9HphAD3qdAElVMAABavaCYKCeChQYDIKAOCDo4OEZVk6DCgiNDQ8iS-cXAUlFqAAFRmFYF401Rm11ck8pARsVKrmmMSFrboq6wL1XYVvZNUFVhEpesIFqttosDqdxBdbo9Xp9AE0AIxQf0DtFUeVKDPxzDAADkqjkkAQECUUage4ATMfVPPUQlz6ongQKQpC3MoV43veUAuI+ZgKEoujxl435Xie5TCMIiDbqqAASyFwPKUDRlA3KILIx7AIW3yHuMjYOBWVZ-qIpLUV+BB0QxlwLpUtY+jhSZXtA9h1OiJ6ZviFgQDeyZQGAmCIG8yDclAkmDvakm6oCSmCVAwhaByGh1twyAuEo9Z2GAEjJDU7YmGWzRaNoyRxCKnSmIO1TTk5oSlK5HbjpUnlgX2goTMkYSrBoGzJKpaIxHEbChBpAIQPFIjZGyXBVvWJwmco5mIJZ+a6Ixg4lVxAUQLxG5bu6npvvWiYkcgIFePYDi6UhAikJeLypi6jhQmYmACICCbQKRFjHLFCQoZJ5DwRmWaRWgYYQpayB5r8S4+rGgmSbcqbpuJijcpYcDQAmN5UeyADqA0ONwOUEMZpkFUV226BSTHAOVKKaVVzBAA))

```
type ActionName = "Play" | "Stay";

type RequestD<A extends ActionName, B extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  _tag: "Request";
  _action: A;
} & B;

type ResponseD<A extends ActionName, B extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  _tag: "Response";
  _action: A;
} & B;

type PlayRequest = RequestD<"Play", { a: number }>;
type PlayResponse = ResponseD<"Play", { b: number }>;

type StayRequest = RequestD<"Stay", { c: number }>;
type StayResponse = ResponseD<"Stay", { d: number }>;

type ActionOf<X> = X extends RequestD<infer A, any>
  ? A
  : X extends ResponseD<infer A, any>
  ? A
  : never;

// Problem:
// X is "Play" | "Stay"`
// Is there a way to get "Play"?
type X = ActionOf<PlayRequest>;

type TagOf<X> = X extends RequestD<any, any>
  ? "Request"
  : X extends ResponseD<any, any>
  ? "Response"
  : never;

// Problem:
// Y1 is "Request" and that's expected
// Y2 is "Request" as well and that's unexpected, how is this possible? How can I fix it?
type Y1 = TagOf<PlayRequest>;
type Y2 = TagOf<PlayResponse>;

type RoundTrip<
  A extends ActionName,
  Req extends RequestD<A, any>,
  Res extends ResponseD<A, any>
> = {
  _action: A;
  request: Req;
  response: Res;
};

type PlayRT = RoundTrip<"Play", PlayRequest, PlayResponse>;

// Problem:
// The following should be wrong because the first request is related to action "Stay", not "Play"
// Is there a way to enforce that?
type WrongRT = RoundTrip<"Play", StayRequest, PlayResponse>;
```

My questions stated in the code above are:

1. How can I associate the "Play" action to a request/response to use it at type level?
2. Why I cannot differentiate between Request/Response even if those types are appropriately tagged (`_tag` field)?
3. How can I constraint the action to be the same action in request/response in `RoundTrip` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually quite simple, you are using `any` as the second parameter in `Request` and `Response`.

If you take a look at your definition:

```js
type RequestD<A extends ActionName, B extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  _tag: "Request";
  _action: A;
} & B; // note that you are extending the entire object.
```

Then when you then define a generic as such:

```js
type TagOf<X> = X extends RequestD<any, any>
  ? "Request"
  : X extends ResponseD<any, any>
  ? "Response"
  : never;
```

It will fail because `any` includes an object such as `{  _tag: "Request" }` for a response or `{ _tag: "Response" }` for a request.

It basically gives typescript nothing to work off of. To fix this you just need to change the `any` to something like an empty object `{}`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBe9xw)

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer to the question number 2, any clue on the others?

Comment: Wait, it fixes also the problem number 3, only number 1 remains, any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, you are right on all accounts, by using `RequestD<any, {}>` and `ResponseD<any, {}>` in `ActionOf` I get the correct answer. Thanks!